# How to embed Wufoo form in Ember application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, wufoo

My client has asked me to integrate a Wufoo form into their Ember application, and provided the following JS (anonymized):

```
<script type="text/javascript">var abc123;(function(d, t) {
var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
'userName':'example',
'formHash':'abc123',
'autoResize':true,
'height':'491',
'async':true,
'host':'wufoo.com',
'header':'show',
'ssl':true};
s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
try { abc123 = new WufooForm();abc123.initialize(options);abc123.display(); } catch (e) {}};
var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');</script>
```

I've tried including it in index.html and also creating a custom component, but keep getting an error from Wufoo:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Is there a way to use the provided Wufoo JS in an Ember.js app?